# My custom jQuery accordion script breaks in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, accordion

Forgive my amateur coding, but I've smashed together a crude page that uses jQuery accordion and loads the content of each drawer from a php file:

http://timdenee.com/yourmaj_preview/accordion_test2.html

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but I get a javascript error in Internet Explorer and the whole thing fails.

For the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong with it... Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: _Only_ in IE 8?  Surprisingly, some people still use one of the five very different versions going back 10+ years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol, I think you can get rid of this:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jQuery 1.1.2 is not quite the latest version.

Comment: I'm torn between a +1 and a _"not a real answer"_ flag.

Comment: hah, getting rid of that fixed it, thanks man! Sorry about for my stupid question, I'm new to this...

Comment: Now, I'm glad I picked the +1 instead of the flag.  @timdenee, don't forget to "accept" his answer.